# How do you add sentinel to Laravel project?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, cartalyst-sentinel

I have this method:

```
$user=Sentinel::findById($user->id);
$reminder=Reminder::exists($user)? : Reminder::create($user);
$this->sendEmail($user, $reminder->code);
return redirect()->back()->with(['success'=>'reset code sent']);
```

However it shows an error, `Undefined type 'App\Http\Controllers\Security\Sentinel'`

Does anyone know how to remove this error?

Answer (score 0):

After installing the package, open your Laravel config file located at `config/app.php` and add the following lines.

In the `$providers` array add the following service provider for this package.

```php
Cartalyst\Sentinel\Laravel\SentinelServiceProvider::class,
```

In the `$aliases` array add the following facades for this package.

```php
'Activation' => Cartalyst\Sentinel\Laravel\Facades\Activation::class,
'Reminder'   => Cartalyst\Sentinel\Laravel\Facades\Reminder::class,
'Sentinel'   => Cartalyst\Sentinel\Laravel\Facades\Sentinel::class,
```

Source: https://cartalyst.com/manual/sentinel/5.x#laravel-8